# Chrome Extension: Should request FS quota while having unlimited access from extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, offline-storage

I have a Chrome extension and I am using the offline storage to store some data. 
I have set the `unlimitedStorage` permission inside the manifest file, so I can access as much storage as the machine allows.

Does it make sense to request the quota as mentioned in the [manual page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage)?

Another question is: I try to ask for more storage than it's available on the machine, and it's granted with no error (e.g. I have a 500GB disk and I ask for 10TB). Is this a bug or an expected behaviour?

Here's the code I use:

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(10*1024*1024*1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {console.log(grantedBytes)})

> 10995116277760
```

Obviously if I check the granted quota I get the correct amount:

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
    function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
        console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
    }, 
    function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);

> we are using  396897753  of  970267000281 bytes
```

I am only confused by the `requestQuota` not returning an error when requesting more than the actual available storage.

Comment: Failing if you ask for more space than is available on the machine would leak information about the machine's configuration to your app. Not giving you an error is, probably, for security reasons.

Comment: You dont need to request quota.